# GW150914 gravitational wave detection incident analysis

Tags: signal-processing

I'm analyzing [the data from LIGO project](https://losc.ligo.org/s/events/GW150914/GW150914_tutorial.html), about first detection of gravitational waves. In one of the many threads here, someone said when I want to do an ASD of the strain I should use `PeriodogramArray` (where 1/dt=4096.):

```
PeriodogramArray[data, Round[1/dt], 1, HannWindow]
```

I used it, but the resulting density is much less than in the original tutorial. The order of magnitude of the density I've got is about ten to -43... What could be the reason of that? Someone else did the signal processing of those data?

Tom

Comment: Can you link to the LIGO data please, for convenience?

Comment: https://losc.ligo.org/s/events/GW150914/GW150914_tutorial.html  everything is here :)

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Yes, it may seems similar. Yet my problem is that the function PeriodogramArray does not give me the expected result. In thread you mentioned, Mr. Russell just said the PeriodogramArray should work in the case, but didn't tell anything more precisely about it :)

Comment: I think all you have to do is take the square root to get from the power to the amplitude spectral density. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong.

Comment: Ohhh PeriodogramArray "returns the SQUARED magnitude of the discrete Fourier transform (power spectrum) of list."... I need to learn reading comprehension in English first and then use the formula. Thank you :)